# Visual Studio App Center prepare separate git for Build

Tags: git, xamarin, azure-devops, visual-studio-app-center

I´m trying to correctly refrence my additional github library for my xamarin.android build in Visual Studio App Center.
The Library is contained in a seperate git repo and then refrenced in my Visual studio project.

[image]

To include the Library in the i added a "appcenter-post-clone.sh" file which should load the git so the reference can still work.

echo "Custom_AppCenter_Script"

echo $APPCENTER_SOURCE_DIRECTORY

echo $PWD

git clone https://github.com/Mygit/Reponame.git

---The Build output:---

Custom_AppCenter_Script

/Users/vsts/agent/2.148.0/work/1/s

/Users/vsts/agent/2.148.0/work/1/s/Flux/Flux.Android

Cloning into 'Aurora'...

##[section]Finishing: Post Clone Script

##[section]Starting: Set Mono version

.....

WARNING: Project file /Users/vsts/agent/2.148.0/work/1/s/../Aurora/Aurora/Aurora.csproj cannot be found.

How do i have to adjust the script so the library is at the correct place?

Comment: You should consider having it as a git submodule instead of having a script checking it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a Soulution:

Added the git as a submodule to the Repository and then changed the  "appcenter-post-clone.sh" to this:

echo "Custom_AppCenter_Script"

git clone --recursive https://github.com/Mygit/Reponame.git

echo "Cloning completed."